# Returning a list of integers and using .contains()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-4

I am new to C#, ASP.NET, MVC, LINQ and nearly everything else I'm doing.  We've developed a working prototype of an event scheduling system that lists all events for all sites without regard to what site is scheduling what event.  We are adapting the prototype to a full release and now want the schedulers to only see events for the sites they schedule.

My initial attempt is to populate a list of integers containing the ID of the sites the scheduler can schedule  I would then  use .contains to determine if the events are in the logged-in user's list of sites.  So I have the following query which works (note that the user cannot yet select multiple sites which is why I am using .FirstOrDefault() because we have some data issues we're working with the customer to address.  Also note that I've included the full method further below):

```
int site = (from u in context.Employees
    join hf in context.SiteHomeFacs on u.Default_Location_Code equals hf.HomeFac
    where u.User_ID == usr
    select hf.siteID).FirstOrDefault();

var sites = new List<int> {site};

return sites;
```

Now I want to default some roles to being able to schedule all sites and this is where I start having problems (full method here):

```
public List<int> GetUserSites(string usr)
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new DBcontext())
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Owner") || HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Controller"))
            {
                var everySite = (from s in context.Sites
                                 select new List<int> { s.ID });

                return everySite;

            }
            var site = (from u in context.Employees
                join hf in context.SiteHomeFacs on u.Default_Location_Code equals hf.HomeFac
                where u.User_ID == usr
                select new List<int> { hf.siteID }).FirstOrDefault();

            return sites;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

The error at 'return everySite' is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

To me it seems counter-intuitive that the query would be acceptable with `.FirstOrDefault()`, but not without it.  Can someone help me to return a list of integer values so I can use .contains? Or suggest a better way over all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this issue , you can do this,

Add a [**`ToList()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) at the end to convert the IQueryable result returned to an IList,

```
 var everySite = from s in context.Sites select s.ID ;    
 return everySite.ToList();
```

**EDIT:**
In order to support large list you could return a HashSet as mentioned in the comment below ,

```
return new HashSet<int>(everySite);
```

Comment: If your list is long and you need to do a lot of checking, I would use a HashSet instead of a List - performance is much much better for lookups. return new HashSet<int>(everySite);

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `select new List<int> { s.ID }` should be `select s.ID`.

Comment: ToList worked but only after I remove the new List<int> {s.ID}--which makes sense.  Thanks also for the note about using a HashSet.  So far the site list is small.  Will work toward using it anyway.